# SLES 12.4| systemd-coredump[<PID>]: Failed to parse resource limit: <daemon_name>

Tags: linux, kernel, systemd, sles, core-dump

I am using SLES 12.4 VM where I have a custom daemon dumping core frequently as I see from `/var/log/messages` and `coredumpctl`. But I never see a core file in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` or in any other location. I do see an error in `/var/log/messages` as:

```
systemd-coredump[<PID>]: Failed to parse resource limit: <daemon_name>
```

I have already set core size limit to unlimited in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Also I have enabled application core dumping in `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf`. However, when i manually run:

```
[ 12.4 sles ~]# kill -SEGV <daemon PID>
```

I am able to find the core in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`.

***/etc/security/limits.conf:***

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

*                soft    core            -1
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
```

***/etc/systemd/coredump.conf:***

```
[Coredump]
Storage=external
Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=5G
#ExternalSizeMax=9G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
#MaxUse=
#KeepFree=
```

***/etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf:***

```
kernel.core_pattern=|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %p %u %g %s %t %e
```

***Ulimit status:***

```
[12.4-sles:~]# ulimit -c
unlimited
```

How do I get the core for the kernel initiated core dump?

Comment: I'm not an SLES user, so I'll point you to these documents I found, in case they're helpful: [How to obtain application core dumps](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=3054866), [How to obtain systemd service core dumps](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7017137)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the contents of your `/etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf` are incorrect, there should be an additional `%c` there between the `%t` and `%e` fields.

You can see that in the change that introduced support for passing the `ulimit -c` around to systemd-coredump to decide whether to save or truncate the coredump file (in other words, to respect the `ulimit -c` setting.)

That change required a change in command line of the `kernel.core_pattern` sysctl, but it seems in your system the old version of that file is present.

This might be due to RPM thinking it needed to preserve the original file (look for a `/etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf.rpmnew` or another `.rpm*` extension might give you a clue.)

In any case, updating that file should solve the problem for you.

---

For more into root causing this issue, I looked at the message you reported:

```
systemd-coredump[<PID>]: Failed to parse resource limit: <daemon_name>
```

I then found that message [here in the source tree](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/coredump/coredump.c#L343), but that code is expecting to receive an RLIMIT that can be parsed into a number, so when you mentioned you get that message with the `<daemon_name>` there, it struck me as the fields you're getting are in the wrong order...

Looking at your `50-coredump.conf` and comparing it to the one from the upstream tree quickly led me to the conclusion that the problem you're having is most likely due to that mismatch.

Comment: The error message is no longer visible. But I see a different message as: `Core dumping is disabled for thr process: <daemon_name>` and still I don't see a core file...